# Motor control using an RPi zero

Tags: servo, dc-motor

I want to control a small 5V servo motor (2 pin) with my RPi zero, but I don't know how to achieve this.

I just need the motor to turn on for a set time e.g 30 seconds, and then turn off, so I figure it should be a relatively simple solution.

But, I only want to motor to be powered only via the pi itself, and not a battery pack. I want this device to operate largely autonomously for long periods of time and I don't want to have the risk of a battery going flat, so I need the motor to be powered by the GPIO board. Is this possible? I assume it is, as it is only a 5V motor that is readily powered by the GPIO board. The only issue is turning the motor on and off when required.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It always amuses me when people don't know how to do something but decide it is simple. There are hundreds of tagged servo - have yo done any research? What is a "GPIO board"?

Comment: `motor to be powered only via the pi itself` ... that makes the pi act as an expensive fuse

Comment: `not a battery pack`  ... where do you expect the power to come from? ... the Raspberry Pi is not a power generator ... the required current will be the same, no matter which route it takes from the battery to the motor, and you definitely do not want that route to go through the pi

Comment: Two pin sounds like a DC motor (servos have 3 pins).

Answer (score 0):

I do this almost aready but using 3V, yes eventually the motors will have their own 5V power supply, currently only one motor being used for testing.

Using a logic level shifter (Youmile DR-YM-342) you can control 5V devices from the Pi's GPIO I2C pins, 3V on the Pi side 5V on your other devices side powered from the Pis 5V pins. From the 5V side of the level shifter use a I2C I/O expander such as MCP23017 and finally a TB6612FNG H Bridge Motor Controller.

You could use a few level shifters connected to GPIO pins instead of the MCP23017 and then on to the TB6612FNG if you are not bothered about using up your GPIO header and not control the motor by I2C.

But note: My motor is not power hungry, it's a motorised POT.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).